# How can I change transfer function slope after a certain point?

Tags: diodes, transfer-function, voltage-clipping

I need to design a circuit for the following transfer function.[image]

I've tried using biased parallel clippers, but the only thing I've managed to do is clipping the output at 5V i.e the slope becomes zero. Do I need to use opamp or something to make the slope non zero i.e amplify the signal?

N.B it's not a homework question :)

Comment: Homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: slope = Gain or attenuation. The nonlinear solution depends on what you choose to draw ok?  There is no one solution for all V/I curves or Vo/Vi slope.

Comment: it’s not homework :) Also I've edited the question adding what I've done so far

Answer (score 1):

(considering this might be homework)
Try using a circuit with resistors and some diodes, remember that the diode can be approximated as a device that conducts nothing if the voltage through it is bellow some voltage (usually 0.7 V) and that after that it has "almost no" resistance. The big tip here is, that transition point in the characteristic curve is related to the diode.

Since it is not a homework question, I would do as such,
I would make a passive circuit with a diode that has the output ratio being
$$ \text{for }V_{in}<2.5V :~~~V_{out} = V_{in}\frac{R_2+R_3}{R_1+R_2+R_3} = V_{in}\frac{1}{2},$$

$$ \text{for }V_{in} \geq 2.5V :~~~V_{out} = 2.5 + (V_{in}-2.5)\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} = (V_{in}-2.5)\frac{1}{6} + 2.5,$$

Which leads to,
$$ R_1 = 5R_2,$$
$$ 4R_2 = R_3.$$

Using \$ R_2 =220 \Omega \$, then \$ R_1 =1100 \Omega \$, \$ R_3 =880 \Omega \$. To get the desired ratios you want (1/2 and 1/3) multiply the output by two with some amplifier (amp op or transistor one). Beware that this is not precise and that the "knee" of the transition might be big and if you need a sharper transition a different circuit will be required.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1rFOa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I should have said what I've done so far. I've edited the question. By the way, it’s not homework :)